# Is the vanishing commutator of observables outside the light cone only a necessary or also a sufficient condition for causality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, causality, observables, locality

The equal-time commutator of observables in QFT has to vanish outside the light cone in order to ensure causality. Mathematically spoken, $[ \bar{\psi}(x)\Gamma_1\psi(x),\bar{\psi}(y)\Gamma_2\psi(y)]|_{x^0=y^0}=0$ for space-like separations $(x-y)^2<0$, where $\Gamma_{1,2}$ are e.g. the gamma matrices $\gamma^\mu$.

Is the vanishing commutator only a necessary or also a sufficient condition for causality? In other words, are there any theories in which the commutator vanishes outside the light cone, but causality is still violated?

The reverse question [has already been asked before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52037/theories-with-non-vanishing-commutators-outside-the-lightcone) (but the given answer is not sufficient in my eyes): are there theories in which the commutator is non-vanishing outside the light cone but the theory is still causal?

Comment: How do you define causality here, and also do you mean in flat space or not